# Firebase Authentication like session for SAAS

Tags: php, firebase, authentication, saas

I'm developing a Saas app to manage a system. I'm using firebase with google identity platform to assign a tenant to each of my users + 1 for my saas tool. So each of my users can have their tenancy hold their clients authentications.

Now usualy i do this with php and mysql so it's easy knowing if a user is logged in or not with sessions but going over to Firebase it's mainly using javascript.. specificaly a authListener to know if a user is logged in or not.

My problem is i want users to log in using the firebase auth systems but the in my platoform pages i want to check in php if a user is logged in or not so i can redirect before loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar project like this,

anything i create in firebase will automatically create/alter a equivalent table in mySQL

and anything i insert/update/delete in firebase will sync realtime with my mySQL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WSOd.png)